# Makefile generate by CMake contains 'cmake' command

Tags: makefile, cmake

I'm trying to use cmake for the first time and it seam to be good except one things.

In the generated makefile, there are some kind of 'cmake command'. Like :
$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start ... etc ...

I really want to generate makefile without any $(CMAKE_COMMAND).

Is it possible ?

Thx.

Comment: could you maybe add the CMakeLists.txt and the command you invoke to create the makefile?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible for cmake to generate a makefile without any `CMAKE_COMMAND` entries.  It would be helpful if you disclosed why you want to do that, maybe there's something else you could do instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to generate Makefile and ensure me that I can build my source code without Cmake.
I found a solution by just do :
make -i

It will ignore error and a call to cmake append and that work. It's a huge workaround but that's work so...

Thx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can achieve that, because `cmake` executable is used to regenerate `Makefile`s if any of `CMakeLists.txt` are changed.

Comment: This is a separate issue. Command `cmake -E cmake_progress_start` in a Makefile's **rule** is used for nicer printing of the status of the building process. Re-running CMake is forced via appropriate **dependencies** in the Makefile. And, as far as I remember, such dependencies could be eliminated with proper CMake options/flags.

Comment: How do you eliminate dependency on `CMakeLists.txt` itself?